# Unsupported Media Type error with .net core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have jwt web api .net core application. Razor page give the following error. Application run perfect in Swagger and postman.

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-600b42fb68fbfa47dc71ff763d7bfa71-03a493705b62904e-00"}

```
    <form method="post" asp-route="Form" action="api/Auth/LoginUser" id="form">
            <div class="form-group f">
                <label for="InputUsername">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group f">
                <label for="InputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

```
    public void OnPost([FromBody] UserLoginRequest request)
            {
                Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    
                request.username = Request.Form["username"];
                request.password = Request.Form["password"];
            }
```

```
[HttpPost("LoginUser")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserLoginResponse>> LoginUserAsync([FromBody] UserLoginRequest request)
        {
            var result = await authService.LoginUserAsync(request);

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For forms, you should use [FromForm] attribute instead of the [FromBody] attribute.